# Redisson Server Interaction

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I am using Redisson for my Java Application. In their documentation it says redisson creates Objects on any of the redis nodes. What does this mean?

For eg:

```
If I do RSet<String> l_campaign_users_set = redissonClient.getSet("set_key");
```

It returns a RSet object which exists locally. Now any operation I do on it will change the local object and the redis object. Does this mean two Remote calls

```
1) To fetch the Set existing on that key.
2) To perform any operation on that returned result.
```

My application will handle a lot of traffic and I fear if this will be atomic and fast or not?

Answer (score 0):

Most Redisson objects are stateless. All methods invoked on objects either read data stored in Redis or write data into Redis. There are no data stored in local object.

Write operations are executed atomically due to nature of Redis.